# python interactive shell over network

Tags: python, shell, networking, interactive

I want to have a full python interactive shell over network (something like the default interpreter that come with a python install). Is there an easy way to get an interactive python shell on a remote computer using a socket ? I can't use SSH and don't care about security. Preferably, I just want to use modules that come with python by default.

Edit : I don't want that the interactive shell create a window on the client side. It should not be visible on the computer.

Comment: You should specify *why* you can't use SSH.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use netcat:

```
python | nc -l -p 9090 &
```

Then connect to it using telnet

```
telnet $HOSTNAME 9090
```

Comment: The remote computer will mostly be running Windows where netcat is not available

Comment: What do you want to do?, the question is still unclear... Is this for teaching or hacking?

Answer (score 1):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) includes a Python REPL server that supports telnet access (SSH too, in case you ever manage to get an SSH client installed).

```
$ twistd -n  manhole --telnetPort tcp:50023
2014-04-06 11:14:01-0400 Log opened.
2014-04-06 11:14:01-0400 twistd 12.0.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.3) starting up.
2014-04-06 11:14:01-0400 reactor class: twisted.internet.pollreactor.PollReactor.
2014-04-06 11:14:01-0400 ServerFactory starting on 50023
2014-04-06 11:14:01-0400 Starting factory <twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory instance at 0x2836c20>
```